# How to play YouTube video in react native Android app without YouTube branding?

Tags: android, react-native, youtube

We want to play some YouTube videos in my React Native app without YouTube branding. We would like to give the user experience as if the video is playing in a native player. We already tried with webview, react-native-youtube-iframe but still, we are not able to achieve our goal. Either top or bottom section has a YouTube logo, then watch and share options are visible. We want to eliminate those. Any possible way to do this in React Native?

Comment: Do you have any reason for not just merging audio and video streams obtained using `yt-dlp -g "VIDEO_ID"`?

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to achieve the similar thing in one of my android app if you can somehow use this particular library

This is an android library and as you mentioned you want to do it in android.

[android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)

I have used this library where i used a player with custom control which helps you override the controls and also this share and next button and even the youtube logo.

Let me know if you need any help further.

Edit:

To enable web UI

```
IFramePlayerOptions options = new IFramePlayerOptions.Builder().controls(1).build();
```

Then initialize the player with this controls.

You won't see any logo now.

Comment: Could you please explain more? We tried this library and we are not able to overcome the mentioned issues.

Comment: Check the edited answer. If you still face the issue do let me know.

Comment: FYI, I'm using React Native Android app not native Android

Comment: You can integrate this particular thing in react native from andorid

Answer (score 0):

URLs of Youtube videos are different for normal videos and embedded videos.

```
Normal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGQwd1_dpuc

Embed: https://www.youtube.com/embed/DGQwd1_dpuc
```

Please change **`'watch?v='`** with **`'/embed/'`**.

You can also hide controls and information by passing '`showinfo=0`' or '`controls=0`'.